# PHP retrieve output from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name value=". $inventory['part_name']. " </td>";
```

When I print this, it only shows "air". However, what is stored inside the database is "air filter". What is the problem? It only prints until before the space. Is there any other way to show the text include after the space text? The above code is inside the PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quotes around the html attributes, and the closing angle bracket for your `input` element.

Try this:

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='". $inventory['part_name']. "'></td>";
```

Note this assumes you won't have a single quote in your `$inventory['part_name']`, might be good to escape that.

Answer (score 0):

As described by [*jszobody's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35989690/4198099), you have missed quotes and `>` before `</td>` tag.

Simply write:-

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='{$inventory['part_name']}'></td>";
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way is that always separate **HTML** and **PHP** so that easily readable. you can do in following format. In this format error are reduce.

```
<td>
   <input type='text' name='name' value='<?php echo $inventory['part_name']; ?>'>
</td>
```